# Why does this dynamic sql query return the value of the variable instead of the actual value?

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I have a conflict matrix stored in a table. I am trying to find the value 
table[course1][course2] but sql refuses to cooperate.

This refuses to work at all:
Says invalid column index but don't know why.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1(course1    IN  VARCHAR2,
                                       course2    IN  VARCHAR2,
                                       conflicted OUT VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT :col1 FROM conflict_matrix_male WHERE course = :col2'
    INTO conflicted
    USING course1, course2;

    dbms_output.put_line(conflicted);
  END procedure1;
```

So I tried doing this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1(course1 IN VARCHAR2,
                                       course2 IN VARCHAR2) AS
  conflicted1 VARCHAR2(200);
  BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT :col1 FROM conflict_matrix_male WHERE course = :col2'
    INTO conflicted1
    USING course1, course2;

    dbms_output.put_line(conflicted1);
  END procedure1;
```

This compiles and runs but it returns whatever you pass into course1 instead of the value in that column. It's not dynamically replacing the contents of the variable into the query.

My last attempt was this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE checkconflict(course1    IN  VARCHAR2,
                                          course2    IN  VARCHAR2,
                                          conflicted OUT VARCHAR2) AS
  query_str VARCHAR2(1000);
  BEGIN

    query_str := 'SELECT ' || course2 ||
                 ' FROM conflict_matrix_male WHERE course = ''' || course1 || ''';';

    dbms_output.put_line(query_str);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query_str INTO conflicted;

    dbms_output.put_line(conflicted);

  END checkconflict;
```

I ran the sql query printed in the first `dbms_output` and it worked perfectly. But the procedure is not working. I think the error is a simple one but i have no idea what it is.

EDIT:

What is stored is a somewhat like an adjacency matrix. The column names are names of courses except the first column.
The first column is named course.
It looks somewhat like this.

```
     Course     CCES1234        CEEN1235       GEEN8234        Conflicts
     CCES1234       1               1             0              2
     CEEN1235       0               1             0              1
     GEEN8234       1               1             1              3
```

But much bigger. My goal is to be able to take the names of two courses and return the value.

For example:

- `checkConflict('CCES1234', 'CEEN1235')` should return 0
- `checkConflict('Geen8234', 'CCES1234')` should return 1.

Comment: Could you formulate more precise what it is you are trying to do and what the table structure looks like?

Comment: I altered my answer based on your edit. I think it should now work for you.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example you're using the columnnames as parameters. You can't do this. Parameters can only be used to replace values, not column names or table names.

EDIT: Reviewing your new edit, it's now clear that course1 is a column NAME, and course2 is a column VALUE. So what you want, seems to be this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure1 (course1 IN VARCHAR2, course2 IN VARCHAR2,             
Conflicted OUT VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'SELECT ' || course1 || ' FROM conflict_matrix_male WHERE course = :crs2'
USING course2
INTO Conflicted;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Conflicted);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this produces the same error: invalid column index. I only used PL/SQL because searching on google returns PL/SQL methods of creating dynamic queries.. How would I go about doing this using regular sql? Any good links?

Answer (score 1):

In your last example, you inverted `course2` and `course1`, so I think that

```
query_str := 'select '|| COURSE2 ||' from Conflict_matrix_male where course  = ''' || Course1 || ''';';
```

should be

```
query_str := 'select '|| COURSE1 ||' from Conflict_matrix_male where course  = ''' || Course2 || ''';';
```

But you can also use the binding, just not for the column name:

```
execute immediate 'Select '||course1||' from conflict_matrix_male where course = :col2'  
  into conflicted using course2;
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio. It doesn't make much of a difference. It's a matrix where the column names are a list of courses with one extra column used as column to store the name of each course for the rows.

Comment: The point is that it doesn't matter. I honestly expected that last example to work, but I have no idea why the value is not getting store into Conflicted.

Comment: BTW, the third example prints these errors, then does the first print statement, then exits:                                      ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at "SCH.CHECKCONFLICT", line 13
ORA-06512: at line 9

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace 
procedure CHECKCONFLICT
(
    COURSE1    in varchar2,
    COURSE2    in varchar2,
    Conflicted out varchar2
) as
query1 varchar2(200);
begin
    query1:= 'select ' || COURSE2 || ' from Conflict_matrix_male where course =''' ||    Course1 || '''';
    execute immediate query1
    into conflicted;
    dbms_output.put_line(conflicted);
 end;
```

Careful with single quotes and the semicolons.
Also, why not use a function? I always found them to be easier to use.

```
create or replace 
function  CHECKCONFLICT4
(
    COURSE1    in varchar2,
    COURSE2    in varchar2
) 
return number
is Conflicted number;
query1 varchar2(200);
begin
    query1:= 'select ' || COURSE2 || ' from Conflict_matrix_male where course =''' || Course1 || '''';
    execute immediate query1
    into conflicted;
    return conflicted;
end;
```